# How do I scale a Matrix by a Double with breeze

Tags: scala, linear-algebra

I am using the [Breeze](https://github.com/dlwh/breeze) library's math part and have the following Matrix:

```
val matrix = breeze.linalg.DenseMatrix((1.0,2.0),(3.0,4.0))
```

I want to scale this by a scalar Double (and add the result to another Matrix) using one
of the `*=` and `:*=` operators:

```
val scale = 2.0
val scaled = matrix * scale
```

This works just fine (more details in my answer below).

**Update** <s>This code does work in isolation. I seem to have a problem elsewhere. Sorry for wasting your bandwidth...</s>

**Update 2** However, the code **fails to compile** if I specifically assign the type `Matrix` to the variable `matrix`:

```
val matrix: Matrix[Double] = breeze.linalg.DenseMatrix((1.0,2.0),(3.0,4.0))
val scaled = matrix * scale // does not compile
```

The compiler keeps complaining that it "could not find implicit value for parameter op".

Can anyone explain this please? Is this a bug in Breeze or intentional? TIA.

Comment: One wild guess, try `val scaled = scale :* matrix`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those of you who struggle with Scala and the Breeze library, I would like to detail some of the functions / operators available for Matrix instances here.

Our starting point is a simple `Double` matrix (`Matrix` and the related operations also support `Float` and `Int`):

```
scala> val matrix = breeze.linalg.DenseMatrix((1.0,2.0),(3.0,4.0))
```

You can easily pretty-print this using

```
scala> println(matrix)
1.0  2.0
3.0  4.0
```

Breeze supports operators that leave the left operand intact and those that modify the left operand - e.g. `*` and `*=`:

```
scala> val scaled1 = matrix * 2.0 // returns new matrix!
scala> println(matrix)
1.0  2.0
3.0  4.0
scala> println(scaled1)
2.0  4.0
6.0  8.0
scala> println(matrix == scaled1)
false

scala> val scaled2 = matrix *= 2.0 // modifies and returns matrix!
scala> println(matrix)
2.0  4.0
6.0  8.0
scala> println(scaled2)
2.0  4.0
6.0  8.0
scala> println(matrix == scaled2) // rough equivalent of calling Java's equals()
true
```

The hash codes of both variables indicate that they actually point to the same object (which true according to the javadoc and can be verified by looking at the sources):

```
scala> println(matrix.##)
12345678
scala> println(scaled2.##)
12345678
```

This is further illustrated by:

```
scala> val matrix2 = breeze.linalg.DenseMatrix((2.0,4.0),(6.0,8.0))
scala> println(matrix == matrix2)
true
scala> println(matrix2.##)
34567890
```

Comment: Are you sure that "You can verify that both variables actually point to the same object by looking at their hash codes"? It is usually not the case that equal hashcodes imply identity, it usually doesn't even imply equality (http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05273/index.html#N10184).

Comment: My point is somewhat justified by **exclusion** (see the final part of my answer). Also, `matrix` and `scaled2` are already checked for equality. Since IMHO the only other data that can possibly enter into the hash code are memory locations, I assume that identical hash code in combination with a successful check for equality is at least an indication for object identity.

Comment: Indicate - maybe, but it still doesn't imply it. See this illustration: http://ideone.com/6DyM4